# Gsub on a Fixnum? undefined method `gsub' for 55:Fixnum

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, gsub

With the following function, I go to a site, crawl some information, am returned some JSON, and put it into the `@price` instance variable.

The JSON that is returned to me is a number, but if the number is greater than 1000, then the number will contain a comma, so I gsub it out.

```
  def iteminfo(id)
    url = "http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/api/catalogue/detail.json?item=#{id}"
    page = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
    info = JSON.parse(page.text)
    namefinder =  info['item']['name']
    pricefinder = info['item']['current']['price']
    name = namefinder
    @price = pricefinder.gsub(',', '').to_i
  end
```

I've already tried this:

```
if pricefinder.to_i > 1000
  @price = pricefinder.gsub(',', '').to_i
else
  @price = pricefinder.to_i
end
```

which gets rid of the error, but messes up the math that is performed on `@price` How can I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears you need to accommodate getting *either* a number or a string. There a number of ways to handle it, but one would be:

```
@price = pricefinder.to_s.gsub(',', '').to_i
```

Answer (score 2):

The error states that you're trying to call the method `gsub` on an object of type `Fixnum` (This tells me that you're dealing with strings and with numbers at the same time).

Something like this might work:

```
pricefinder.to_s.gsub(',', '').to_i
```